# Does DateTimeFormatter Have Anything Like The Joda's DateTimeFormatter#withOffsetParsed() method?

Tags: java, date, datetime, date-format

I've got a problem with the new Java Date-API, especially the `java.time.DateTimeFormatter`.

I'm looking for a way to add the TimeZone-Offset to a given time.

e.g.

```
 "2016-05-27 14:22:00 UTC+2"
```

should be parsed to

```
 "27.05.2016 16:22:00"
```

(using the pattern "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss")

This is my problematic code:

```
LocalDateTime time = LocalDateTime.now();
LOG.debug(time.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
```

The formatting results in a time-string which matches the given pattern, but without considering the offset of the local TimeZone.

Comment: Do you want 16:22 (as in: add 2 hours to the date in the initial string) or do you want 12:22 (as in: the local time in UTC time zone)? If the former, you probably need to manually parse the end of the string, if the former you can use an OffsetDateTime first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the many ways of applying time zone, offset and formatting. It will help switching between Joda and Java 8 time.

**Java 8 date/time api**

```
String input = "2016-05-27 14:22:02 UTC+0200";
DateTimeFormatter parser = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss 'UTC'Z");
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss");
LocalDateTime localDateTime = parser.parse(input, LocalDateTime::from);
System.out.println(localDateTime); //2016-05-27T14:22:02
//Apply different offset on the above instant.
OffsetDateTime offsetDateTime = parser.parse(input, OffsetDateTime::from).withOffsetSameInstant(ZoneOffset.of("+07:00"));
System.out.println(offsetDateTime); //2016-05-27T19:22:02+07:00
//Apply different timezone on the above instant.
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = parser.parse(input, ZonedDateTime::from).withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("Asia/Jakarta"));
System.out.println(zonedDateTime);// 2016-05-27T19:22:02+07:00[Asia/Jakarta]
//Apply formatting
System.out.print(formatter.format(zonedDateTime));//27.05.2016 19:22:02
```

**Joda api**

```
String input = "2016-05-27 14:22:02 UTC+0200";
DateTimeFormatter parser = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss 'UTC'Z");
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss");
LocalDateTime localDateTime = parser.parseLocalDateTime(input);
System.out.println(localDateTime);//2016-05-27T14:22:02.000
//Apply the above offset to the date time
DateTime offsetParsedDateTime = parser.withOffsetParsed().parseDateTime(input);
//Change to new Offset
DateTime jakartaDateTimeOffset = offsetParsedDateTime.toDateTime(DateTimeZone.forOffsetHours(7));
System.out.println(jakartaDateTimeOffset);//2016-05-27T19:22:02.000+07:00
//Change to new Zone
DateTime jakartaDateTimeZone = offsetParsedDateTime.toDateTime( DateTimeZone.forID("Asia/Jakarta") );
System.out.println(jakartaDateTimeZone);//2016-05-27T19:22:02.000+07:00
//Apply formatting
System.out.print(formatter.print(jakartaDateTimeZone ));//27.05.2016 19:22:02
```

Comment: That helped. Thanks

Answer (score -2):

Yes you can specify a offset you'd like to take in account. 
You can do this in several different ways but I'll share
some piece of code that will get you going.

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'", Local.US);
```

This is an example of how to create a formatting object with the set of pattern and offset.

Comment: @assylias Sorry about that, just wanted to provide a quick example.